# How much voltage would be required for a charge to have 1 amp of current with 0 resistance?

Tags: charge, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, vacuum

Voltage is the energy a charge has. If a charge has some energy it will move forwards. Resistance opposes the charge and it moves slower.

But what if resistance was exactly 0.

1--->How much **voltage** would we need to supply to a charge so that it has **1A** current?

2--->How much **current** would we get with just **1 volt** supplied to a charge?

More clarification: I want to know how much voltage would we need to supply to have 1A current with 0 resistance and how much current would pass with 1 volt energy supplied to a charge, keeping resistance at absolute 0.
To justify the 0 resistance imagine the charge is in vaccume with nothing to oppose it.

The voltage can not be 0 because if you have 0 voltage you won't be able to start any current with it. I want to know how much voltage should be supplied to stationary charges initially so that they start moving with a current of 1A when there is 0 resistance

Comment: Read about superconducting magnets such as are used in MRI scanners and in physics experiments. Current flows in the superconducting (zero resistance) coil of the maget practically forever with no voltage, and without any source of power.

Comment: Well we had to supply some voltage in order to achieve the flow of current. Moreover even superconductors offer some resistance just that it's extreamly small. I'm talking about absolute 0 resistance.

Comment: Read about superconducting magnets. Especially, read about how they are "ramped up." You are correct in that, voltage is applied to "ramp up" the current and store energy in the coil's magnetic field. But once the desired current is achieved, the coil is shorted out—0V—and the current continues to flow. FYI: There is no specific voltage that gives you 1A of current. The _rate of change_ of the current when ramping up or ramping down is proportional to the voltage. The current itself is independent of the voltage that was used.

Comment: P.S., Not sure why you think that the difference between real-world superconductors and an ideal zero-Ohm circuit would significantly change the answer to your question. Maybe you could explain.

Comment: @Egg superconductors do not have some resistance. It is zero

Answer (score 0):

Ohm's law is $V=IR$.

For $R=0\mathrm{\ \Omega}$ resistance the amount of voltage for $I = 1\mathrm{\ A}$ of current would be $ I R = 1 \mathrm{\ A} \ 0 \mathrm{\ \Omega} = 0\mathrm{\ V} = V$ by direct application of Ohm's law.

For $V = 1 \mathrm{\ V}$ the amount of current would be $$\frac{V}{R} = \frac{1 \mathrm{\ V}}{0 \mathrm{\ \Omega}} = undefined$$ It is not possible to put any non-zero voltage across such a conductor.

Vacuum is not a conductor with $0 \mathrm{\ \Omega}$ resistance. You should be thinking about superconductors.

Comment: Vaccum has no resistance at all, so it's resistance will be 0. That's why I chose that scenario. And some people from this website had pointe dme jn another question that Ohm's law doesn't apply to vacuum. So we can't اس eit to explain anything regarding this.

Comment: Vacuum does not have 0 resistance. The only sense that vacuum has resistance is the impedance of free space, which is about 377 Ω. And that isn't even really a resistance. It doesn't make sense to talk about the resistance of free space because free space doesn't follow Ohm's law. You can put two electrodes in space and change the voltage all you like without producing any current. That completely contradicts assigning it any resistance, and especially contradicts saying that the resistance is 0 since 0 resistance would imply that it is impossible to have voltage. Resistance just doesn’t apply

Answer (score 0):

No voltage would be required. The already moving charges of 1 ampere (1 C/s) would just keep moving since nothing is restricting them, so they do not need a voltage to keep them going.

Of course this is an unrealistic scenario since electrical resistance is unavoidable in general. (Only certain specialised materials and scenarios can be considered as zero-resistance conduction, such as superconductors. They often require specialised environments.)

Comment: But if the voltage will be 0 that means electrons will have no energy. If they don't have energy how will they start moving in the first place?

Comment: @Egg They won't start moving. But they also won't stop if they are already moving. Voltage is not the "energy of an electron" but rather the energy difference (per charge) between where the electron is and where it is going. The electron can still carry kinetic energy and thus be in drift motion without voltage. But only theoretically, because with the slightest resistance present then it will stop.